# what are the meanings of these bolded phrases?

Tags: meaning-in-context, american-english

1. Jean Louise’s aunt often held up Cousin Joshua to her as a family example not lightly to be discountenanced: he was a splendid figure of a man, he was a poet, he was cut off in his prime, and Jean Louise would do well to remember that he was a credit to the family. ***His pictures did the family well***—­Cousin Joshua looked like a ratty Algernon Swinburne.
2. The train clacketed through pine forests and honked derisively at ***a gaily painted bell-funneled museum piece sidetracked in a clearing.*** It bore the sign of a lumber concern, and the Crescent Limited could have swallowed it whole with room to spare. Greenville, Evergreen, Maycomb Junction.

Thank you

Comment: How have you tried to answer this question yourself?

Comment: Yes, I was wondering about museum piece part.

Answer (score 4):

> he was a credit to the family. His pictures did the family well

His pictures looked good and so made the family look good.

> a gaily painted bell-funneled museum piece sidetracked in a clearing

[image]

The picture shows an old-fashioned, brightly painted, bell-funneled locomotive. You can look up bell-funnel, museum-piece, sidetrack and clearing in a dictionary.

**EDIT** in response to another answer

The modern-day train was moving (clacketing). It passed a siding (a side-track) on which was parked an old-fashioned locomotive - a museum piece. The driver of the more modern train hooted derisively at the old engine. The old-fashioned and out-dated locomotive was marked with the sign of a lumber company. –

Comment: Thank you Chasly, you mean the pictures by him make the family looked good?

Comment: No, I mean the pictures ***of*** him by a photographer had a beneficial effect on the family in general.  However it would make things a lot easier if you gave the source of the quotation and, if possible, a link to it. You have the advantage of the full context.

Answer (score 0):

It helps to understand the context of the quotes.  They are from Harper Lee's *Go Set a Watchman*. Louise, the daughter of Atticus Finch, is musing about her family on a train trip home.  She remembers her aunt (her father's sister) describing Cousin Joshua (presumably, the aunt's son) in glowing terms.

Painting the family in glowing terms is the aunt's habit, and Louise [notes](http://www.theguardian.com/books/2015/jul/10/harper-lee-new-novel-first-chapter-extract-to-kill-a-mockingbird) that

> Her father had a way of undermining his sister’s lectures on the
>   innate superiority of any given Finch: he always told his daughter the
>   rest of it ....

The description of Cousin Joshua is Louise's report of her aunt's description -- he cut a striking figure, he was a poet cut off prematurely, he was a credit to the family.  But Louise knows better.  Cousin Joshua wasn't a splendid figure; he was a "ratty" version of the poet Swinburne.  He really wasn't much of a poet; his only work was a slim volume of self-published verse.  And Louise knows he wasn't a credit to the family because her father has told her the whole story:  while at the university, Cousin Joshua took a dislike to and a potshot with a firearm at the president of the University.  Cousin Joshua was then confined to an insane asylum ("state accommodations for the irresponsible") for the rest of his life.

The sentence "The pictures did the family well" ordinarily might mean that the pictures depicting Cousin Joshua **reflect credit** upon the family.  But given what we know about the aunt's propensity to exaggerate about the Finch family, it might also mean that the pictures **accurately portray** the family -- not as grand as the aunt would have everyone believe.

This perhaps foreshadows the telling of the rest of story of Atticus Finch, which undercuts his heroic portrayal in Lee's *To Kill a Mockingbird*.

Comment: @shelley The bold phrases are two possible interpretations of "did the family well."  Does that make sense to you?

Comment: I think the first one, "reflect credit" makes more sense! cause the sentence before it declaring he was the credit of the family.

Comment: @shelley The sentence before it does *not* declare that Cousin Joshua was a credit to the family.  It reports that his own mother (the aunt) declared that Cousin Joshua was a credit.   Which is different.  As I explained, Cousin Joshua turned out to be no credit at all:  he attempted to shoot the president of his university and spent the rest of life in an insane asylum.

Comment: I know he wasn't a credit to the family. you think he was the credit of the family just in his photos, not in the real life?

Comment: I think he was a credit to the family only in his own mother's mind.  You know he wasn't; I know he wasn't; and most importantly Louise knows he wasn't.  And it's her thinking that's reported.  She says that her Cousin's "ratty" picture "did the family well."  How can "ratty" reflect well on the Finches?  (On my family, sure.)  I think there's a good chance that she's being ironic.  Remember that her father Atticus has told her the real story about "any given Finch."

Answer (score -2):

In context; the first bold sentence means --

**--the pictures made the subjects look (aesthetically) better (or more-attractive) than the writer believed them to be *in actuality.***

The second sentence (again. I culled the meaning from it's context) the bold phrase means --

**--the building looked old, particularly small and bell-shaped.**  It is a lumber manufacturing plant, which the reader may presume to be a large building. (Or a large complex of buildings). Relative to the train, it looks small enough in "the clearing" that the train could eat it without much effort "swallowed whole with room to spare."

The writer describes this seemingly-large building to be three-times smaller than the reader might create it by:

1. Using metaphor to compare it to something placed against a wall inside a museum.
2. Accenting the relative size comparison by giving us some facts about what it IS and using personification to describe the train as being so big that it could "swallow" the building.
3. Accenting the scale of this personified abstraction by appending "with room to spare."

The writer is using some nice prose to establish the *relative* smallness of the possibly-bigger object (**the building**) and the *relative* massiveness of the possibly-smaller object (**the train**). Using this colorful depiction of relative size--- from  the writer's perspective, **it should be clear to the reader that the train looks/feels/sounds MUCH MUCH MUCH bigger than the lumber manufacturing building.**

An old, albeit large building, *could* appear small relative to the train passenger when cast in "a clearing" The implication is that the former background (or from the writers perspective,  the current background) is filled with large trees. A "lumber concern" in "a clearing" is almost assuredly surrounded by dense forest with thick & tall trees. The writer is asserting how big the train FEELS and how small the building SEEMS. At the same time the writer is showing us the sense of being in motion at high speed OUT OF a FOREST and into a developed, treeless zone. The writer also expresses the relative masssive-ness of the surrounding forest (natural setting) to the relative smallness of the clearing (man-made setting).

*It could be that the train is ACTUALLY absurdly larger than the building. It could be that the "lumber concern" REALLY is absurdly small, but from the context there is no way to tell for sure...*.

**However it doesn't matter how big or small they may "really" be, only that you understand that the train FEELS big and the lumber yard *seems* small in comparison.**

Edit in-response. I acknowledge the correctness of chasly's answer inside a larger context, but I maintain there was NO WAY to know that the "museum piece" was a in fact, a SECOND train. Only that the mysterious "museum piece" "bore the sign of a lumbering concern" I posit that the OP's question illustrates some good-to-know differences in the way EN-US readers interpret antiquated passages written in EN-UK when we don't have the cultural context in our heads or a historical concordance to such prose at our disposal.

Should I have run the fictional-sounding character's name through a search-engine? *Maybe.*In the case of THIS question *I should not have needed to.*

I accept the hit on the downvote but maintain I provided correct answers to the OP's questions...at the same time I posit that the *question* should've provided more context.

That the "the museum piece" is a *second train* and that "Ratty Algae Swineburnt" (purposely mis-spelled) is REAL (and apparently attractive **photographer**) as opposed to a fictional character illustrates the pitfalls of EN-reader interpretation. As a native speaker I don't wish ESL on my worst enemy.

...If English questions get interpreted differently, the problem lie with English itself, or lack, thereof within the question.

To conclude, this question falls somewhere along the range of SNAFU, TARFU and FUBAR. *Nu?*

Comment: You have it wrong. The museum-piece is the locomotive. The bell is a description of the type of funnel that was used on these old locomotives.  Here is a picture of a bell funnel. http://www.easytradingmall.com/images/Home/H7710_20099.jpg  - Compare it with the picture I gave of the locomotive.

Comment: I acknowledge the potential error, but the quote says "the train clacketed through pine forrests..." Trains make a "clacketing" noise as they roll down a track. "Clacket" is most-likely onomatopoeia used for rhetorical effect, this COULDN'T happen unless it were IN MOTION (unless the entire passage is allegorical to what the writer feels when he SEES the museum piece), this seems exceedingly abstract but makes sense in a wider context (not the posted passage alone though).  Perhaps "clacketing" is being interpreted differently in EN-UK than my native EN-US?

Comment: P.S. I disagree with your interpretation of the first sentence as well. You say, "*the pictures made the subjects look (aethetically) [sic] better (or more-attractive) than the writer believed them to be in actuality.*"  This seems to imply that Cousin Joshua is the photographer. You cannot get that from the context.

Comment: The modern-day train was moving (clacketing). It passed a siding (a side-track) on which was parked an old-fashioned locomotive - a museum piece.   The driver of the more modern train hooted derisively at the old engine. The old-fashioned and out-dated locomotive was marked with the sign of a lumber company.

Comment: Ok then explain the OP's "--Cousin Joshua looked like a ratty Algernon Swinburne." In this style, the two dashes tell ME the writer is switching back to reality as opposed to the abstract portrait. I'm not misinterpreting "ratty" that mean UNattractive in any English subset. I admit I have no idea what an "Algernon Swinburne" is but SOUNDS ugly, abrasive "piggish" [Swin_] and "burnt" [burne]. That we disagree is proof it isn't strongly-written prose (Unless it comes from a British period piece or a passage written so long ago I have no hope of understanding it without a concordance....)

Comment: Algernon Swinburne was a real person - a famous writer. Here's a picture - he looks pretty ratty already. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algernon_Charles_Swinburne  - Joshua was also a poet and perhaps he cultivated the 'Swinburne look' in order to appear more important. He cannot have looked too bad himself because he is earlier described  as 'a splendid figure of a man'.

Comment: Thank you guys for the explanations. you don't think "museum piece" is the big sign which has shown the name of those three counties. I mean like a road sign?

Comment: Regardless, we are interpreting "His pictures" differently. You read it as pictures BY him. I read it as pictures OF him (I'm certain this is a another quirk between EN-US and EN-UK. "Cousin" makes him part of the family and the name's sound/description place his reality at odds with the abstraction. Edit: OP: no, the sign definitely not the "museum piece" I read it to be the "lumber concern" and chasly is probably correct in larger context that there are TWO trains and ONE of them is a "museum piece" -- real or imagined.

Comment: I think there's little doubt that the modern train is honking at an old-fashioned train and not a building.  The object of the modern train's derision is a "museum piece," i.e., something so old as to be suitable for display in a museum, which never applies to buildings.  The museum piece is "sidetracked," i.e., sitting on a parallel piece of railroad track, which never applies to buildings.  And the modern train would only be (metaphorically) contemptuous of another (lesser) train, not a building.

Comment: That's a good point I never made the connection of "sidetracked" to the OTHER train I interpreted to be a building or complex of buildings. I guess I got sidetracked when I read it.

Comment: If "sidetracked" wasn't enough, there's "the Crescent Limited could have swallowed it whole with room to spare" obviously refers to a train line, meaning that the museum-piece would have been nothing compared to the Crescent Limited trains. There's enough contextual clues in the short piece given in the question, so it's not so open a matter of interpretation.

Comment: What you just quoted only implies that the objct is BIGGER and is not implicit to what it IS. It is never explicity defined to be ANOTHER train except for the word "sidetracked" the rest is colorful description ...having now read the passage a few times, it is refering to two trains, other than "sidetracked" the other object is NOT explictly defined. It could be anything. You are reading far too much additional information into it from extraneous content we hashed-out earlier. "Context clues" are not sufficient to tell a story, it isn't supposed to be a puzzle.

Comment: @shelley thank you for the post I learned a great deal. It took me out of the encapsulated world of EN-US in which I read and speak a dialect only heard in the Los Angeles Metroplex. Even though we have a subway and major train hub (Union Station) - the word "sidetracked" was lost on me. I even polled some associates and none of them made the connection either. Sidetracked morphed into an abstract psychological description...it's been stripped of its root-meaning. I learned something new and that beyond valueable. Humble thx to you and chasly.